# Independent Laravel Eloquent, integration in other framework

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, slim

I am using super light Slim framework. I would like to use Laravel Eloquent model binding, but I am fetching data from REST API and not from database. It's possible to integrate Eloquent in my project? Thanks

Comment: Oddly enough we have something for this. http://www.slimframework.com/docs/cookbook/database-eloquent.html

Answer (score 3):

If you have a composer.json file inside your project you can simply add it.

```
"require": {
    "illuminate/database": "^5.2"
}
```

Running a composer update will pull in the required packages.

or you could run `composer require illuminate/database` in terminal inside your project folder.

The database component contains a Capsule manager class,that takes care of creating a Laravel container and loading the required classes.

You can simply follow the readme at https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Ok, its possible to change data source from mysql databse to REST API? Or what wrapper class should I change or extend? Thanks

Comment: Eloquent is a a database connection wrapper building sql queries in a easy to use php format. Thus eliminating your need to prepare, open connections, executing queries and closing connections.

Comment: I understand. I would like to use model binding same as in Laravel, but as main data source use REST API not sql database. Thanks